# Prevent menu to show outside window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a `ul` as a contextual menu in a php-file-listing application.

I recently added this piece of code to move the menu when the cursor is too close from the borders of the window, in order to prevent the menu to be drawn partially outside of the window.

```
if ((PosY + elm.outerHeight()) > $(window).height()) {
  PosY = PosY - elm.outerHeight();
}
if ((PosX + elm.outerWidth()) > $(window).width()) {
  PosX = PosX - elm.outerWidth();
}
```

But…
**Sometimes** the code works, and the menu is moved,
And **sometimes** it doesn't work, and the menu is displayed as below:
(Let's say it doesn't work like 1 out of 5 times)

[image: Menu is outside !]

I tried consoling the variables but they seem to be correct and I really don't understand why it is happening.

Here is a working snippet, where I managed to reproduce the problem.
(As it is an extract of my code, much of the CSS is missing but that's not important.)

```js
// Global vars
var PosX = 0;
var PosY = 0;

// Mouse mouve
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
  return;
});

/*
 CONTEXT MENU
*/
// Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$(document).on("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the regular one
  event.preventDefault();
});
// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).on("mousedown", function(e) {
  // If the clicked element is not the menu
  if ($(e.target).parents(".ContextMenu").length == 0) {
    // Hide it
    $(".ContextMenu").fadeOut(100);
  }
});

// On context menu…
function ContextMenu(id) {

  elm = $("#" + id);

  /*
  console.log("PosY:", PosY);
  console.log("elm H:", elm.outerHeight());
  console.log("win H:", $(window).height());
 
  console.log("PosX:", PosX);
  console.log("elm W:", elm.outerWidth());
  console.log("win W:", $(window).width());
  */

  // Moves menu if out of screen
  if ((PosY + elm.outerHeight()) > $(window).height()) {
    PosY = PosY - elm.outerHeight();
  }
  if ((PosX + elm.outerWidth()) > $(window).width()) {
    PosX = PosX - elm.outerWidth();
  }

  // Hide and reopen the menu required
  elm.fadeOut(100, function() {
    elm.css({
      "top": PosY,
      "left": PosX
    }).fadeIn(200);
  });
  //console.log("Context menu on: " + elm);
  return false;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  color: #000;
}

p,
input,
label,
button,
a {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

#InTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}


/* Scrollbar */

#Table::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#Table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
}

thead th {
  padding: 4px 0;
}

thead th i {
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: #CCC;
}

thead th,
tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tbody td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tbody td:first-of-type {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*overflow: hidden; */
}

tbody td img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 32px;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) td {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#Table th,
#Table td {
  position: relative;
}

#Table p {
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.ContextMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #333;
  /* Smoothy color */
}

.ContextMenu div {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.ContextMenu div:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 2px solid #AAA;
}

.ContextMenu li {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ContextMenu img,
.ContextMenu i,
.ContextMenu span,
.ContextMenu p {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ContextMenu img,
.ContextMenu i,
.ContextMenu span {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style media="" data-href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css"></style>

<body class="tblr0 bg" id="DropBox" contenttype="text/html; charset=UTF-8" onload="" onresize="">
  <div class="abs t40blr0" id="Content" style="top: 100px;">
    <div class="abs tblr0 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto" id="Table" style="opacity: 1;">
      <table class="tblr0" id="InTable">
        <thead class="bg-silver align-l">
          <tr style="width: 100%;">
            <th data-sort="int" id="Icos" style="width: 68px; min-width: 68px; max-width: 68px;"><p>Icon</p><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th data-sort="string" id="Name" style="width: 291.333px;">
              <p>Filename</p><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th data-sort="string" id="Type" style="width: 218.5px;">
              <p>Type</p><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr onclick="" oncontextmenu="ContextMenu('ContextMenu0');" style="width: 100%;">
            <td data-sort-value="0" style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Icons" style="line-height: 64px; font-size: 60px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Name">
                <p>.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>[Current]</i></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <p>&lt; Current Directory&nbsp;&gt;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <ul class="ContextMenu" id="ContextMenu0">
                <div onclick="context_menu_close(event);">
                  <p>Tools</p>
                </div>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                  <p>Create new Folder</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                  <p>Create new File</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                  <p>Upload files in current folder</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                  <p>Download current folder as Zip</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr onclick="" oncontextmenu="ContextMenu('ContextMenu1');" style="width: 100%;">
            <td data-sort-value="1" style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Icons" style="line-height: 64px; font-size: 60px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Name pr4">
                <p>Acces<span class="opac06">&nbsp;</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <p>&lt;&nbsp;Directory&nbsp;&gt;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <ul class="ContextMenu" id="ContextMenu1" style="top: 218px; left: 854.625px; display: none;">
                <div onclick="context_menu_close(event);">
                  <p>Tools</p>
                </div>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-i-cursor"></i>
                  <p>Rename</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
                  <p>Move</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="far fa-copy"></i>
                  <p>Copy</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  <p>Delete</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                  <p>Download folder as Zip</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Can someone enlighten me?
What is wrong with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code in your snippet appears to work fine - at least for me in Chrome on windows. If I click 'Acces' the menu appears to the right of he cursor. If I click '<Directory>' it appears to the left.

Comment: Try clicking again, and again and again on the right of the `tr`, sometimes, I swear, it doesn't work. I'm on Chrome Windows, too.

Comment: I have done. Repeatedly right clicking works absolutely fine.

Comment: I just did again, and I've got the problem. I don't know why I do and you don't… :/ Maybe, try right-clicking on the same tr all along. I think I don't have the problem when I clicked on the first and then the second.

Comment: take it easy Takit Isy, it happened to me to, ~1% of the times, but does happen, so there is no leprechaun toying with your mind, the problem exists, I'm in Firefox BTW

Comment: Thanks @J.M.Echevarría, I feel much better knowing I don't have a leprechaun… :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem lay around `.fadeOut(100)` and `.fadeIn(200)`. Those are animations and as such, they run asynchronously regarding the rest of the code.

To be honest, I am not qualified to provide you with a thorough explanation as to why and HOW this was happening in your code. Basically: the process of **updating `posX` and `posY`** and the process of ***hiding* and *showing* the menu** were overlapping. Note that with your code as is, if you take your time (~1sec) between each click, the problem never occurs, whereas if you start clicking away repeatedly it breaks more and more often, just another hint that the animation's time is the source of the problem.

The solution: put **updating `posX` and `posY`** inside ***hiding* and *showing* the menu**. Specifically inside the callback after hiding the menu, before showing it again.

LET ME KNOW IF THE LEPRECHAUN RESURFACES!

```js
// Global vars
var PosX = 0;
var PosY = 0;

// Mouse mouve
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  PosX = e.pageX;
  PosY = e.pageY;
  return;
});

/*
 CONTEXT MENU
*/
// Trigger action when the contexmenu is about to be shown
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(event) {
  // Avoid the regular one
  event.preventDefault();
});
// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {
  // If the clicked element is not the menu
  if ($(e.target).parents(".ContextMenu").length == 0) {
    // Hide it
    $(".ContextMenu").fadeOut(100);
  }
});

// On context menu…
function ContextMenu(id) {

  elm = $("#" + id);

  /*
  console.log("PosY:", PosY);
  console.log("elm H:", elm.outerHeight());
  console.log("win H:", $(window).height());
 
  console.log("PosX:", PosX);
  console.log("elm W:", elm.outerWidth());
  console.log("win W:", $(window).width());
  */

// Hide and reopen the menu required
elm.fadeOut(100, function() {
  // Moves menu if out of screen
  if ((PosY + elm.outerHeight()) > $(window).height()) {
    PosY = PosY - elm.outerHeight();
  }
  if ((PosX + elm.outerWidth()) > $(window).width()) {
    PosX = PosX - elm.outerWidth();
  }
    elm.css({
      "top": PosY,
      "left": PosX
    }).fadeIn(200);
  });
  return false;
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  position: fixed;
  color: #000;
}

p,
input,
label,
button,
a {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: inherit;
}

#InTable {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-bottom: 800px;
}


/* Scrollbar */

#Table::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

#Table::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #000;
}

thead th {
  padding: 4px 0;
}

thead th i {
  margin-left: 4px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  color: #CCC;
}

thead th,
tbody tr {
  cursor: pointer;
}

tbody td {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tbody td:first-of-type {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*overflow: hidden; */
}

tbody td img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 32px;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) td {
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}

#Table th,
#Table td {
  position: relative;
}

#Table p {
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.ContextMenu {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border: 2px solid #888;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #333;
  /* Smoothy color */
}

.ContextMenu div {
  background: #e8e8e8;
  height: 16px;
  padding: 4px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #CCC;
}

.ContextMenu div:not(:first-child) {
  border-top: 2px solid #AAA;
}

.ContextMenu li {
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style-type: none;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ContextMenu img,
.ContextMenu i,
.ContextMenu span,
.ContextMenu p {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.ContextMenu img,
.ContextMenu i,
.ContextMenu span {
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style media="" data-href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css"></style>

<body class="tblr0 bg" id="DropBox" contenttype="text/html; charset=UTF-8" onload="" onresize="">
  <div class="abs t40blr0" id="Content" style="top: 100px;">
    <div class="abs tblr0 overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto" id="Table" style="opacity: 1;">
      <table class="tblr0" id="InTable">
        <thead class="bg-silver align-l">
          <tr style="width: 100%;">
            <th data-sort="int" id="Icos" style="width: 68px; min-width: 68px; max-width: 68px;"><p>Icon</p><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th data-sort="string" id="Name" style="width: 291.333px;">
              <p>Filename</p><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
            <th data-sort="string" id="Type" style="width: 218.5px;">
              <p>Type</p><i class="fa fa-sort"></i></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr onclick="" oncontextmenu="ContextMenu('ContextMenu0');" style="width: 100%;">
            <td data-sort-value="0" style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Icons" style="line-height: 64px; font-size: 60px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Name">
                <p>.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>[Current]</i></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <p>&lt; Current Directory&nbsp;&gt;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <ul class="ContextMenu" id="ContextMenu0">
                <div onclick="context_menu_close(event);">
                  <p>Tools</p>
                </div>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-folder"></i>
                  <p>Create new Folder</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-file"></i>
                  <p>Create new File</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-upload"></i>
                  <p>Upload files in current folder</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                  <p>Download current folder as Zip</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr onclick="" oncontextmenu="ContextMenu('ContextMenu1');" style="width: 100%;">
            <td data-sort-value="1" style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Icons" style="line-height: 64px; font-size: 60px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <div class="Name pr4">
                <p>Acces<span class="opac06">&nbsp;</span></p>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <p>&lt;&nbsp;Directory&nbsp;&gt;</p>
            </td>
            <td style="height: 64px;">
              <ul class="ContextMenu" id="ContextMenu1" style="top: 218px; left: 854.625px; display: none;">
                <div onclick="context_menu_close(event);">
                  <p>Tools</p>
                </div>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-i-cursor"></i>
                  <p>Rename</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>
                  <p>Move</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="far fa-copy"></i>
                  <p>Copy</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                  <p>Delete</p>
                </li>
                <li onclick=""><i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                  <p>Download folder as Zip</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, leprechaun hunter, it seems that your formula successfully made it disappeared ! :)